# How to collect data from google form and store in jsonfield in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

How to collect data from google form and store in JsonField in Django?

I am expecting to collect all the responses and save them in my database in JsonField
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try requests

```py
import requests

url = "" 
response = requests.get(url).json
```

`response` will be a dictionary of your json web response

---

```py
import requests
from django.db import models

class foo(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()

url = "" 
response = requests.get(url).json

foo.objects.create(data=response)
```

Docs:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.1/#jsonfield-for-all-supported-database-backends

Comment: but how can i collect data once the response is submitted?

Comment: How to add to the database?

Comment: I need to collect data from google form then store it in my database in jsonfield

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are after, but I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you boy but i a still confused how can i collect data from google form before saving to jsonfiled

Comment: Ohhh Google Forms, yeah sorry that is a bigger problem. You'll need to create an API token ([tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collecting-data-with-google-forms-and-pandas/)). Why not make the form with Django?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link with me. making the form with Django could have solved the problem but i have to follow instructions.

Comment: No worries, keep exploring your options. Good luck!